# Android - Parse query to get all posts and the users to go with the posts

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, pfquery

I have made an application where users can log in and post text to my Parse database. All posts are held in a text column inside a Posts class, another column in this class is user which is a pointer to my User class which has a column called username, it is the username string that I would like to retrieve.
 I've managed to query the database and retrieve all of the data within the text column, put it all into a string array and then into a listview in my app.
 what I would like to achieve next is to retrieve all of the posts in the text column and the name of the user that posted each one by looking at the related username column within Posts.
 Can I do this all in one query or should I create another query to do this?

Parse classes:
**User**
| objectID (String) | username (String) | password (String) |
**Posts**
| objectID (String) | text (String) | user (Pointer<_User>) |

the user would start app, register a username and password which adds a row to the User class containing their username and password. The user would then make a post which would add a row to the Posts class containing text and a pointer to the user that made the post within the user column.

query and ListView code:

```
    //create new ArrayList and ArrayAdapter
    final ArrayList<String> postList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row, postList);


    //create new ParseQuery selecting all data within 'text' in descending order
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
    query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("text"));
    query.addDescendingOrder("text");

    //query
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> text, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                //query successful

                int listSize = text.size();

                //loop through each post in 'text'
                for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){

                    //add each post to textArray
                    textArray[i] = text.get(i).getString("text");
                }

                //add all data in textArray to ListView
                postList.addAll(Arrays.asList(textArray));
                lvText.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }

            else {
                //query error

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "query error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather simple, you can use a [.include](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-relational) on an existing query to "Include the [class you want to include] data with each [Class you're querying]" and you can call the queried object I believe as follow:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("text"));
query.addDescendingOrder("text");
query.include([field containing user reference]);

ParseObject parseUser = text.get(i).getParseObject(([field containing user reference]);
```

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

"I forgot to mention that my 'user' column within the Posts class is a **pointer** to the objectID of the user within my User class. **Within** the User class is a **username column**, this is the information that I would like to feed back to my application.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("text"));
query.addDescendingOrder("text");
query.include("user");

String parseUserName = text.get(i).getParseObject(("user").getString("userName");
```

It might be that this does not work, with an error saying you have to refresh the object to get the data. But first try this and see if it works it magic, I know some other tricks which are:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("text"));
query.addDescendingOrder("text");
query.include("user");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> text, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
            query.whereEqualTo("objectId", text.get(0).getParseObject(""));
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {
                     String parseUserName = users.get(0).getString("userName");

                }
            });
            int listSize = text.size();

            //loop through each post in 'text'
            for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! very simple. You must have a lot of experience with Parse

Comment: The old saying, been there, done that, spend over 3 months figuring this all out myself. Hence I'm glad to share it with other people as much as possible!

Comment: Haha fair enough! I plan on reading through all of the documentation on Parse queries soon so hopefully no more simple questions from me!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I forgot to mention that my 'user' column within the Posts class is a pointer to the objectID of the user within my User class. Within the User class is a username column, this is the information that I would like to feed back to my application. I've realised that my orignal question didn't quite cover it all

Comment: I realised that by programming it the way I have at the moment, I am asking to return a pointer. What I actually want to retrieve is a username string within my User class that's related to each post in the text column of my Posts class. sorry to confuse

Comment: That's alright, this is where Parse can become a pain in the ass to do it nice and beautifully in one whole query, but I'll give it a shot, updating answe accordingly!

Comment: Thanks man, you're a hero. Sorry my question wasn't clear. I should have explained that I have a seperate User class.

Comment: I've added to my question a little table to show my parse classes