# Parse SDK Android, query with relation using "include" is not working

Tags: android, parse-platform

Parse SDK version: 1.15.8   Parse Server Version:  2.5.0

The table 'Post' has a relation with 'ParseUser' through the 'user' column,

[image]

So I am trying to get all the posts from 'Post' table along with the user who posted it with the following query,

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");

// Include the 'user' relation data in 'Post' table 
query.include("user");


query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Post: "+object.get(0).getParseUser("user")+" "+e);
       }
    });
```

But the user value is always returned as null,

*I/System.out: Post: null null*

the debug also shows empty values,

[image]

Comment: Linking you to another post ->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095887/android-parse-query-to-get-all-posts-and-the-users-to-go-with-the-posts

Comment: Thanks, and I understand the query is pretty straightforward, and as you can see, I have followed exactly the same steps as described in the other stackoverflow thread, but still couldnt get the values.
I am wondering, if it might be a bug with the latest release in parse server.

Comment: you can try contacting their developer support. I once had an issue with another sdk (UberTesters) and their technical support helped me set up it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");

// Include the 'user' relation data in 'Post' table 
query.include("user");


query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Post: "+object.get(0).getRelation("user")+" "+e);
       }
    });
```

Comment: There is no method getUser in ParseObject

Comment: @ThiyagaB Have you try with getRelation(String key)